# Self Containing Form for Heirarchical Data

Tags: ms-access

I'm attempting to store legislation inside an access database. Due to the inconsistent numbering and heading/subheading use, I was intending on storing the data in a flat table, with a "parent" column storing the ID to the heading, or the subheading, or the section text etc etc etc.

So - for instance

```
ID     Section    Parent    Description
0      1                    Purposes of the act
1      a          0         The purpose of this act is to:
2      i          1         Manage data efficiently
3      ii         1         Test access
4      b          0         More data goes here
```

would represent the data

```
1 - Purposes of the act
    a - The purpose of this act is to
        i - Manage Data Efficiently
        ii - Test Access
    b - More Data goes here
```

My issue is in using forms to effectively edit the data. The best approach (from what I see) would be to embed a form within itself as a subform - which is evidently not allowed. My intention was to have 2 new buttons - one for new item, one for new child. The latter which would create a child item and show it (and the other child items) in the subform.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You might look into Cascading combos. Also, you should really consider using a hierarchical structure such as the Nested Set Model or the Adjacency List. Both of them are fairly advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a continuous form displaying the whole law/by-law (you should be able to format it for display in the source query); however, each section could be double-clicked on to open another form (perhaps modal) to edit the section.

Logically, you'd have controls for inserting, deleting, indenting and outdenting particular sections.

I suspect you will also want to include an "order" column for each section. Suppose you want to change the order of 1.a.i and 1.a.ii. You can't change the ID column, because it's probably an Auto-Number.

Of course, an obvious question is why not just store the law/by-law in MS Word and store references to it's location in the DB

Comment: Short answer is due to what we need to do with the information afterwards, and the data we need to attach to the legislation. Excellent idea with the order column. I'll try your method when I get a chance to see if it works.